# Google Cloud organization cloudbuild service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In my Google Cloud console at the Org level I have a couple of service accounts like `<number>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` with this permissions:

[image]

I haven't been able to find where these came from because there are no service accounts at the org level. At least not from the UI.

This is for the Org, not the project level default service accounts that are created. In the project IAM I see both the project and org services accounts

Are these safe to delete? In one org I have one of these and in another Org i have multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's not safe to delete permissions** from these Service Accounts, If you delete GCP Cloud Build services break (services stop working correctly). Your Cloud Build SA Agent has the permissions to create resources in GCP for your project that it needs to operate.

**Usually admins grant IAM permissions(roles) at the project level and resource level also. Please note that the permissions defined at Org/Project level will not be visible when viewing permissions at the resource level, because the projects are also considered another resource.**
.

Refer to [Configuring access for Cloud Build Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-for-cloud-build-service-account):

> Cloud Build uses a special service account to execute builds on your
> behalf. When you enable the Cloud Build API on a Google Cloud project,
> the Cloud Build service account is automatically created and granted
> the Cloud Build Service Account role for the project.

When you create GCP Cloud Build service for a project, Automatically 2 service accounts are assigned roles within your project like below :

1. At the Organization service accounts like `<number>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` with this permission is assigned the `Cloud Build SA Role`. The SA to which you want to grant extra permissions if you want your builds to perform functions such as deploying cloud functions.

> 2. If you use an existing secret, you might need to manually grant the Secret Manager Secret Assessor role to your Cloud Build service
>    account,
>    `service-${PROJECT_NUMBER}@gcp-sa-cloudbuild.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

Named as Cloud Build SA, and is granted the `Cloud Build SA Role` in your project. See the official [Document](https://cloud.google.com/secure-source-manager/docs/connect-cloud-build?hl=en) for details.